# KQL Querying MDE/MDO's API

Tags: azure, api, kql, windows-defender, microsoft365-defender

I am researching a little bit about MDE/MDO-s API capabilities for advanced threat hunt.

my question is:   ***Is it possible to KQL querying MDE/MDO’s API?***

Any info would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

goal: using KQL to hunt for threats utilising MDE/MDO's API.

Answer (score 0):

You may explore the [http_request (GET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/http-request-plugin?pivots=azuredataexplorer) and [http_request_post (POST)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/http-request-plugin?pivots=azuredataexplorer) plugins to send an HTTP request to your API's and convert the response into a table.

Please note that it’s disabled by default for security reasons, I would highly recommend reading the documentation very carefully before you try it as the plugins allow queries to send data and the user's security token to external user-specified network endpoints.

Here are sample query examples for reference:

**http_request (GET):**

```html
let Uri = "https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq 'Azure Purview' and location eq 'EU West'";
evaluate http_request(Uri)
| project ResponseBody.Items
| mv-expand ResponseBody_Items
| evaluate bag_unpack(ResponseBody_Items)
```

**http_request_post (POST):**

```html
let uri='https://example.com/node/js/on/eniac';
let headers=dynamic({'x-ms-correlation-vector':'abc.0.1.0', 'authorization':'bearer ...Azure-AD-bearer-token-for-target-endpoint...'});
evaluate http_request_post(uri, headers)
```